# different ways String Join

Tags: c#, string, winforms, join

Can anyone recommend a better way for joining a string together.

I've got 2 lists which I'm joining together like this:

```
textBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, changesWithValues);
```

However the data I get out has got bit in it that should be there.

My over all code for this bit looks this:

```
private void converToText(Dictionary<string, int> dictionaryList)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> changesWithValues = dictionaryList.ToList();

        display(changesWithValues);
    }

    private void display(List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> changesWithValues)
    {
        textBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, changesWithValues);
    }

    private void Show_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        converToText(_dictionary);
    }
```

Comment: "the data I get out has got bit in it that should be there." , can you give a specific example, both with the inputs and the output, as well as the expected output?  Also this looks like java, don't forget to tag it as such

Comment: *However the data I get out has got bit in it that should be there.* Please explain that sentence better. No idea what that means.

Comment: When I get the data out it look like this:                                                                              [/Tax Marker Ripper v1/Help_Document.docx, 2]                                                 The square brackets [] and the comma should be there I don't know where they have come from

Comment: It not Java it's C# it's a windows form application

Comment: You are joining `KeyValuePair<string, int>` instances, which means that you are going to get the result of calling `ToString` on those objects.  Presumably that is not what you want.  As has been asked, please show us what you actually expect.  We can't read your mind.

Comment: What I'd like to see come out is this                                                                 /Tax Marker Ripper v1/Help_Document.docx             2

Comment: In that case you should use `String.Format` to combine the `Key` and `Value` of each `KeyValuePair` into a single `String`, then `Join` those `Strings` together, e.g. `changesWithValues.Select(kvp => string.Format("/{0}/{1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to combine the `Key` and `Value` of the `KeyValuePair` into the format you want, e.g.

```
textBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, changesWithValues.Select(kvp => string.Format("{0} {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not joining strings but instances of `KeyValuePair`. Thus you are actually using the overload of the `string.Join` method that takes a collection of objects instead of an array of strings as input, which is first applying a `ToString()` to these instances; this gives you strings that contain both the key and the value of the pairs (see [the method reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)).

I guess that you need to concatentate just the keys of the pairs. In that case, this is what you need:

```
textBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, changesWithValues.Select(x => x.Key));
```

Comment: The result that is outputted from this line is                                                           /Tax Marker Ripper v1/Help_Document.docx                                                             The number indicates how many entries each path has. This line cuts off the numerical values